# Workbench Metadata Retrieve error

Tags: metadata

I get this error when trying to export all components of metadata within a sandbox org. UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1787816442-45795 (-673032061)

Comment: Note that this site is not an official support channel for Salesforce (except for the mobileSDK team, kinda). We're just users like yourself. This is a GACK error code, which is only useful to Salesforce support agents (through offical support channels).

Comment: I've checked Salesforce backend logs and see that stacktraceId (-673032061) points to error as `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`. Based on [Metadata Limits doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_metadata.htm) ensure that you are deploying/retrieving up to only 10,000 files at once.